# Favicon only appearing on the homepage?

Tags: favicon

I place my favico `favico.ico` on the root directory of my site.

Add the following code to `wp-content/themes/f2/header.php`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

However, the favicon is ONLY appeared on the homepage? How can I make it effective on the whole site?

---

**EDIT:** I set the `href` as the abosolute path and it works, seeing below:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Running the latest version of WordPress, you can upload a favicon using `Appearance -> Customize -> Site Identity -> Site Icon` which will take care of a lot of this stuff for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the href as the abosolute path and it works, seeing below:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Or as suggested by @Caspar and @Howdy_McGee, for wordpress 4.3+, use:

`Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Site Identity -> Site Icon`

Comment: Or, if you're using WP 4.3+ you can use the site icon setting in the customizer. (Appearance > Customize > Site Identity )